# Python with Django Import error with RegistrationSupplementBase cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy'

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, importerror, django-registration

I'm updating a very old Django project and trying to use `RegistrationSupplementBase` but when importing, I got the error below:

```
File "/home/projectmachine/Desktop/project_rebuild/projectname/models.py", line 11, in <module>
from registration.supplements.base import RegistrationSupplementBase
File "/home/projectmachine/.local/share/virtualenvs/projectname-QrYA9Qp-/lib/python3.6/site-packages/registration/supplements/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils.text import ugettext_lazy as _
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy'
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. It seems like there is an issue with the dependancies installed. I'm using Django 2.2 with `django-inspectional-registration 0.6.2`

Here is how I am importing the class:

`from registration.supplements.base import RegistrationSupplementBase`

Comment: These have been moved to `django.utils.translation`. But anyway these are depraceted. You should replace it with `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`.

Comment: In this case, the error is coming from django-inspectional-registration. It looks like It has [not been updated](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-inspectional-registration) for several years, so it will not support recent versions of Django. You could try forking the code and making the change the Willem suggests, but I suspect there will be other changes required to make it work with Django 2.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I can't figure out what's wrong. It seems like there is an issue with the dependancies installed. I'm using Django 2.2 with `django-inspectional-registration` 0.6.2

The function has been moved to the `django.utils.translation` module, so you can import this with:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Based on the [*Django Deprecation Timeline* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-4-0), `ugettext_lazy` will be removed in [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0). You can use `gettext_lazy` instead:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

Based on the [GitHub repository of **`django-inspectional-registration`**](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-inspectional-registration) however, the project is not active anymore: the latest commit was in november 2016. You can try to update the project, but perhaps it is better to look for an alternative package that works in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll look into other options.

Comment: I was stuck in this issue, thanks